# Get Sheet By Name not working - only accepts one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet connected to a google form, however I have another tab "sheet3" which uses array formula from "Form Responses 1".

The script I am using which sends all questions and answers to other emails does not take the info from "sheet3", only from "Form responses 1".

I have tried so many different things and nothing. Here's my script:

```
function sendFormAnswers(data) { 
Logger.log("sendEmail");


var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var row = values.getLastRow(); 


var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet3").activate();
var headers = s.getRange(1,2,1,s.getLastColumn()-1).getValues()[0];

var values = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),1,s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn()-1).getValues()[0];
var row = values[0];

var timestap = values[0];
var ABS = values[1];
var OPS = values[2];
```

many thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not `Sheet3`?

Comment: How do you call `sendFormAnswers`? It seems `getActiveSheet()` returns what you need.

Comment: Hi all I have tried Sheet3 and sheet3 but no luck at all but as soon as I change to "Form Responses 1" it works. Question and answer but unfortunately I need that fetched from sheet3 as it will have more info to send through email.

Comment: I have just deleted the array formula on sheet3 and the script worked. So i tried importrange and no luck either. So it looks like any formulas here to fetch data will break my script... any ideas guys? many thanks

Comment: sheet3 has 1000 rows and the script its fetching from there which theres no data therefore returning only the questions and not he answers. How can I set the right row? I have tried it by errors keep coming up. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi all. Its now working as I am using =filter instead.